# Nodejs, http post json

Tags: node.js, post, oauth, request, http-post

Here is an example post that I want to do in my Nodejs server to get ClientID and secret.

Request example:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.opskins.com/IOAuth/CreateClient/v1/ \
  --header 'authorization: Basic {{AUTH_HASH}}' \
  --data name=TestApp2 \
  --data redirect_uri=http://localhost:1234
```

Response returns JSON structured like this:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "time": 1535408581,
    "response": {
        "secret": "$nGwYVda@@PErKAUpG#kHQ&YA1L)A*X1",
        "client": {
            "client_id": "ff371b045307",
            "name": "TestApp2",
            "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:1234",
            "time_created": 1535407757,
            "has_secret": true
        }
    }
```

I am trying with request :

```
const request = require('request');

var headers = {
        'authorization': 'Basic ***my-api-key****'
    };

    var dataString = 'name=TestApp2&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000';

    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.opskins.com/IOAuth/CreateClient/v1/',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: dataString
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {

            console.log(body);

    }

    request(options, callback);
```

but getting error output like this :

```
{"status":401,"time":1540115259,"message":"API Key Required"}
```

I have been trying different codes and middlewares but couldn't make it. Also my test works perfect on Postman. I need help to post that and get my client_id and secret.

Comment: In your headers Authorization key is with a capital A. This could be the problem since your log messages said API is missing.

Comment: I thought that also and tried 'Authorization', Authorization, authorization also tried that all with removing Basic key also front of my api key. But non of them worked.

Comment: Try adding "Content-Type"="application/json" in your headers.

Comment: that changed something. Now I am gettin this output :    <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>Malformed JSON request body.

Comment: In your body do as follows body:JSON.parse(dataString), let's see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. It was really tricky for me. I needed to use my API Key and also client id.
Bellow codes worked. Thank you very much vitomadio !

I used [reqclient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reqclient) from npm.

here is my code

```
   var client = new RequestClient({
        baseUrl:"https://api.opskins.com/IOAuth/CreateClient/",
        debugRequest:true, debugResponse:true,
        auth: {
            user:"***My_apikey****",

        }
    });

    var resp = client.post("v1/", {"name": "testApp2", "redirect_uri":"http://localhost:5000/"},{headers: {"authorization":"Basic **my_clientID"}}).then(response => {
       // console.log(response);
    });
```

also I am really curies and would like to know how can I do that with request.